# Configure Apache to not respond to invalid page requests

Tags: apache, http, configuration, raspberry-pi

I have Apache setup on a Raspberry PI. There is only one page on the site. Is it possible to configure Apache to just not respond to requests that are not for the page I have installed?

The main reason for asking it is I can see in the logs that someone is testing the waters to try and hack their way in, i.e. I am seeing things like "muieblackcat" and "phpmyadmin" requests.

I'm not overly worried about them but I'd like it if these requests could simply be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following code in .htaccess file on root. (no need to create extra folder).

```
Deny From All
<FilesMatch "^index\.php$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

Change FileMatch with your file, just keep the syntax.